# Twig array key errors

Tags: templating, php

I'm dumping this var but cant nail down this error:

```
{% set submissions = craft.tumblr.submissions %}
<ul>
    {% for key,submits in submissions %}
        // KEY GIVES ERROR 1
        <li>{{ dump(submits.key)  }}</li>
        <hr>
        // BLOG_NAME GIVES ERROR 2
        <li>{{ dump(submits.blog_name)  }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Error 1:

> Key "key" for array with keys "blog_name, id, post_url, slug, type, date, timestamp, state, format, reblog_key, short_url, summary, recommended_source, recommended_color, followed, is_anonymous, anonymous_name, anonymous_email, is_submission, liked, note_count, title, url, link_author, excerpt, publisher, can_send_in_message, can_reply" does not exist

Error 2:

> Method "blog_name" for object "Twig_Markup" does not exist

Thoughts?

EDIT: Adding scheme for `craft.tumblr.submissions`:

```
array(7) {
  [1]=>
  array(28) {
    ["blog_name"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(11) ""
    }
    ["id"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      int()
    }
    ["post_url"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(64) ""
    }
    ["slug"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(23) ""
    }
    ["type"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) ""
    }
    ["date"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(23) ""
    }
    ["timestamp"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      int()
    }
    ["state"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) ""
    }
    ["format"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) ""
    }
    ["reblog_key"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(8) ""
    }
    ["short_url"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(30) ""
    }
    ["summary"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(23) ""
    }
    ["recommended_source"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(11) ""
    }
    ["recommended_color"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(11) ""
    }
    ["followed"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      bool(false)
    }
    ["is_anonymous"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      bool(true)
    }
    ["anonymous_name"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(13) ""
    }
    ["anonymous_email"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(30) ""
    }
    ["is_submission"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      bool(true)
    }
    ["liked"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      bool(false)
    }
    ["note_count"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      int(0)
    }
    ["title"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(23) ""
    }
    ["url"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(54) ""
    }
    ["link_author"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(11) ""
    }
    ["excerpt"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(11) ""
    }
    ["publisher"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(11) ""
    }
    ["can_send_in_message"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      bool(false)
    }
    ["can_reply"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      bool(true)
    }
  }
  [2]=>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what `submissions` is, but `submits` inside your loop is an array so you can access its values using `submits['blog_name']`.

Comment: For `submits[blog_name]` the error is:
**Variable "blog_name" does not exist**

Comment: What is `craft.tumblr.submissions` using? I can then try and replicate and test to provide a better answer.

Comment: @LukePearce think you were just missing the quotes in your answer.  Should be `submits['blog_name']`. @JMP

Comment: haha of course - that's what you get trying to work things out without code editor highlighting!

Comment: `<li>{{ dump(submits[key]['blog_name'])  }}</li>` gives this error:
**Key "1" for array with keys "blog_name, id, post_url, slug, type, date, timestamp, state, format, reblog_key, short_url, summary, recommended_source, recommended_color, followed, is_anonymous, anonymous_name, anonymous_email, is_submission, liked, note_count, title, url, link_author, excerpt, publisher, can_send_in_message, can_reply" does not exist**

Comment: Just take away the [key] bit